Unable to restore non-consumable IAP StoreKit2
In my application, I used to offer a non-consumable product. This isn't available t purchase anymore. However, if it was purchased, I want it to still be available for those who bought it.
In the past, when it was available, I was working in UIKit with StoreKit and SwiftyStoreKit.
Now I had to shift to StoreKit2.
I followed all of the available tutorials to implement it and everything works, except for restoring the old non-consumable.
To test the purchases, I sent the application both to internal and external testing, and neither I nor the users who already purchased the app could restore the purchase.
The function I use to restore the purchase is the following:
    func restorePurchases() async throws {
        try await AppStore.sync()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
            if case let .verified(transaction) = result {
                print("product is verified")
                if transaction.productID == legacyID {
                    print("Legacy product")
                    await refreshPurchasedProducts()
                    withUnsafeCurrentTask { task in
                        task?.cancel()
                    }
                    await transaction.finish()
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        
        if let legacyTransaction = await Transaction.currentEntitlement(for: legacyID) {
            print("Entitled to legacy transaction")
            await handleTransaction(legacyTransaction)
        
        }
        
        await refreshPurchasedProducts()
        
        
        print("Restored products: \(purchasedProducts)")
    }

private func handleTransaction(_ result: VerificationResult<Transaction>) async {
        print("Will handle transaction of  products")
        switch result {
            case .verified(let transaction):
                print("Product in Verified state")
                switch transaction.productType {
                    case .autoRenewable:
                        print("Subscription product")
                        if let subscription = products.first(where: {$0.id == transaction.productID}) {
//                          purchasedProducts.insert(subscription)
                            if transaction.revocationDate == nil {
                                self.purchasedProducts.insert(subscription)
                            } else {
                                if purchasedProducts.contains(subscription){
                                    self.purchasedProducts.remove(subscription)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        
                    case .nonConsumable:
                        print("Legacy product")
                        if let legacyProduct = legacySubscription,
                           transaction.productID == legacyID,
                           transaction.purchaseDate < legacyDate {
                            purchasedProducts.insert(legacyProduct)
//                          savePurchaseStatus(for: legacyProduct.id, isPurchased: true)
                        }
                    default:
                        break
                }
                
                // Finish the transaction regardless of whether the product was found
                await transaction.finish()
            case .unverified:
                print("Product Transaction failed verification")
        }
    }

    func refreshPurchasedProducts() async {
        print("Will refresh purchased products")
        for await result in Transaction.currentEntitlements {
            print("Refreshing purchased products")
            await self.handleTransaction(result)
            
        }
        entitlementManager.hasPro = !self.purchasedProducts.isEmpty
    }

How can I successfully restore my old non-consumables?
